# How to list top 5 tags in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

I have lot of tags for the project as it is very old and there are many releases to the 
client.

Now when I list all the tags to view it; I ended up with a big list on my terminal.

Is there any command to show the top 5 tags or top 10 tags something like this.

I use

```
hg tags
```

command to list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What exactly do you mean by "top"? Or do you want to only show 5 or 10 from the list?

To accomplish the last thing, use

```
hg tags | head -n 5
```

or

```
hg tags | tail -n 5
```

(if you're using *nix).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have Mercurial-only platform-independent soulution (without *Nix-specific), you can use Mercurial's revsets and templating (BTW, `hg tags` always show unwanted `tip` in list), something like

`hg log -r "last(tag(),5)" --template "{tags}\t{rev}:{node|short}\n"`

In order to decrease typing in process, you can write write (parametrized) revset in `[revsetalias] section on config-file like

```
  [revsetalias]
  lt = last(tag(),$1)
```

and use `hg log -r "lt(<ANY NUMBER HERE>)" --template "{tags}\t{rev}:{node|short}\n"` for getting `<ANY NUMBER HERE>` chronologically newest tags

or define additionally `hg log --template` as new command in `[alias]` section

```
[alias]
latestags = log -r "lt($1)" --template "{tags}\t{rev}:{node|short}\n"
```

and use later `hg latestags(5)` or `hg latestags(10)`